# building docker images makes the Vagrant-managed VBox VM freeze

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, docker, vagrant

Folks

While researching utilizing Docker images for web apps development I've stumbled upon the following issue.

(all commands found bellow are executed inside a Vagrant-managed VBox vm)

1. Create a custom `Dockerfile` and place it in `$HOME/my_app`.

   ```
   FROM ubuntu:14.04  
   RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get install -y \  
       python-dev \  
       python-setuptools \  
       && apt-get clean \  
       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  
   RUN easy_install pip  
   RUN pip install virtualenv
   ```
2. Build the image using the above `Dockerfile`.

   ```
   sudo docker build -t kamils/my_app:0.1 $HOME/my_app
   ```

The build process goes as planned until it finishes the first RUN layer. Then the vm stops to respond. The responsible VBox process goes haywire on the host' CPU (htop shows 200% usage:P).

Any ideas on what is happening or am I doing anything wrong?

**EDIT**

(as per request) `free -m` output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7890       7410        480        612         30        963
-/+ buffers/cache:       6416       1473    
Swap:         7627       1450       6177
```

I should probably also mention that while the host runs on Ubuntu 14.04, the guest vm itself is powered by Arch Linux.

Comment: add to the post the output of "free -m" please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some further digging and the answer turned out rather simple.

The kernel utilized by the Arch Linux Vagrant box I was running does not have "aufs" module built in. While Docker is able to run containers without aufs, provisioning additional layers on top of them may crash the system.

Shame that Docker does not warn the user about aufs not present on the system.

Anyways.. solved.